# Most of the time HTML doesn't load first time

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have this app that I made with Swift, for fun and because I'm a beginner. Basically what it does is you can enter an artist name and song name and it fetches lyrics from AZLyrics.com based on the artist and song name you entered. For some reason most of the time when I try and load lyrics the first time when I open the app it doesn't load (it loads the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc time). Here is my code could someone please tell me how I could fix this?

**First View controller**

```
import UIKit

var lyricsWithQuotes = ""
var urlError = false

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var songName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var artistName: UITextField!

@IBAction func search(sender: AnyObject) {
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/" + artistName.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "").lowercaseString + "/" + songName.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".", withString: "").lowercaseString  + ".html")

    if url != nil {

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

                var urlContentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<!-- Usage of azlyrics.com content by any third-party lyrics provider is prohibited by our licensing agreement. Sorry about that. -->")

                if urlContent.containsString("It's a place where all searches end!") {

                    urlError = true

                } else {

                    var lyricsArray = urlContentArray[1].componentsSeparatedByString("<br><br>")

                    var lyrics = lyricsArray[0] as! String

                    var lyricsWithoutBR = lyrics.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<br>", withString: "")

                    var lyricsWithoutSlashDiv = lyricsWithoutBR.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</div>", withString: "")

                    var lyricsWithoutI = lyricsWithoutSlashDiv.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<i>", withString: "")

                    var lyricsWithoutSlashI = lyricsWithoutI.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</i>", withString: "")

                    lyricsWithQuotes = lyricsWithoutSlashI.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&quot;", withString: "\"")

                }

            } else {

                urlError = true

            }

        })

        task.resume()

    } else {

        urlError = true

    }


}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    artistName.delegate = self

    songName.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
import UIKit

var lyricsComplete = ""

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var lyricsDisplay: UITextView!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if urlError == true {

        urlError = false
        lyricsDisplay.text = "Couldn't find that song!"

    } else {

        lyricsComplete = lyricsWithQuotes
        lyricsDisplay.text = lyricsComplete

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Where are you displaying the lyrics? In the first or second view controller?

Comment: @AJ9 In the second. And I obtain the HTML in the first.

Comment: So you pass lyricsWithQuotes to the second view controller? In your code you've not shown how that is done. I suspect that the request has not completed the first time you go to the second view controller.

Comment: How would I make it so it does go the first time?

Comment: Like I said, you need to show how you are passing lyricsWithQuotes to the second view controller. Is this through a Segue?

Comment: No basically I made a universal variable that stores the lyrics and when I access the second view controller in the viewDidAppear method it should display the lyrics. I want to pass it through a segue because I think that will fix it but I don't know how

Comment: Using a universal variable can be a bad idea, this hasn't been set the first time you reach the second view controller, and is hence blank. Check my answer below.

Comment: Did the answer solve your issue?

Comment: use println(lyricsWithQuotes) to determine if lyricsWithQuote is empty on the first segue. Also I don't know if it is necessary to change the way you perform you segue. it may help and the code would be better, but not necessary. segue can readily be done by use of a button.                                       _            so are you finding that lyricsWithQuotes is empty when you first segue

Comment: I just did that. And it did print but didn't show up in the text view.

Answer (score 0):

After your NSURLSession has completed - basically this line:

```
lyricsWithQuotes = lyricsWithoutSlashI.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&quot;", withString: "\"")
```

You have two options:

**Option One - Programatically launch the view:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "STORYBOARD NAME HERE", bundle: nil)
let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VIEW CONTROLLER IDENTIFIER HERE") as! ViewController2
newVC.lyricsComplete = lyricsWithQuotes
```

If you have a navigation controller:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)
```

If you don't have a navigation controller:

```
self.showViewController(newVC, sender: self)
```

**Options 2 - Trigger the Segue:**

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("SEGUE NAME HERE", sender: nil)
```

Then intercept the Segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if(segue.identifier == "SEGUE NAME HERE"){
        let newVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
        newVC.lyricsComplete = lyricsWithQuotes
    }
}
```

If you use option 2, make sure the Segue is between the View Controllers and not attached to your button:

Like this:

[image: Segue Correct]

Not like this:

[image: Segue Incorrect]

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I tried both of those but for some reason I always for the first one I get signal SIGABRT and for the second one it doesn't crash but it doesn't seem to segue.

Comment: Have you removed all other segues?

Comment: No but I set the segue identifier for the view segue to segueView and used that in my code.